# Convert a BST into preorder and postorder linkedlists

Tags: linked-list, binary-search-tree, in-place, preorder, postorder

This is a round-2 Amazon interview question.Convert a given Binary Search Tree into pre-order and post-order linked lists and this conversion has to be **inplace**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below code is written to do flattening of Binary Tree in pre-Order traversal form without using stack. It uses pre-Order traversal recursive approach. In this, TreeNode[] arr will hold the last most left node value on which I am updating right pointer of that node.

```
    public TreeNode preorderNode(TreeNode root,TreeNode[] arr)
    {
    if(root==null)
        return null;
    if(root!=null && root.left==null && root.right==null)    
        {
            arr[0]=root;
            return root;
        }
    TreeNode temp=root.right;
    if(root.left!=null)
        root.right=preorderNode(root.left,arr);
    else arr[0]=root;
    root.left=null;
    arr[0].right=preorderNode(temp,arr);
    return root;
    }
    public void flatten(TreeNode root) {

        if(root==null || (root.left==null && root.right==null))
            return;
        TreeNode temp=root.right;    
        TreeNode[] arr=new TreeNode[1];
        arr[0]=null;
        if(root.left!= null)
            root.right=preorderNode(root.left,arr);
        else
            arr[0]=root;
        root.left=null;
       arr[0].right=preorderNode(temp,arr);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve the preorder version of the problem, you can slightly modify a simple preorder(Refer code below to see that).

The idea is to construct a doubly linked list from the binary search tree in a preorder traversal. However, we only set the forward links during the traversal.

Let's learn through an example.
If the tree looks like:

```
        4
       / \
      2   6
     / \ / \
    1  3 5  7
```

Then, the linked list should look like:

4 <-> 2 <-> 1 <-> 3 <-> 6 <-> 5 <-> 7.

Now, we only set forward links during preorder traversal. Therefore, our list will look like.

4 -> 2 -> 1 -> 3 -> 6 -> 5 -> 7

The left or previous pointers(not shown above) are still as they were in the tree.
We can set the left pointers through a simple traversal of the list now.

The code below does exactly this.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class node{
    public:
        int data;
        node * left, *right;
        node(int a){
            data = a;
            left = right = NULL;
        }
};

node * head = NULL, *prev = NULL;

void preorder(node * root){
    if(!root)   return;

    //both head and prev aren't set. This node must be the root(and head of our required list).
    if(!head and !prev) head = root;    

    //store the address of root's right child
    node * temp = root->right;

    /*
        If prev is set, make current node it's right child.
        (This is why we save right child's address for every node in temp.)
    */
    if(prev)    prev->right = root;

    //now make the current node prev.
    prev = root;
    cout << root ->data <<" ";

    preorder(root->left);
    preorder(temp);
}

void printll(){
    node * prev = NULL;
    while(head != NULL){
        cout << head ->data << " ";
        head -> left = prev;
        head = head -> right;
        prev = head;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

int main() {

    node * t = new node(4);

    t->left = new node(2);
    t->left->left = new node(1);
    t->left->right = new node(3);

    t->right = new node(6);
    t->right->left = new node(5);
    t->right->right = new node(7);

    preorder(t);
    cout<<endl;
    printll();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void preorder(struct node *head)
{

if (head)
    {
        addToLL(head->data);
        preorder(head->left);
        preorder(head->right);
    }
}
```

In the addToLL() you can just keep adding the nodes to the linked list.

Global Declaration

```
struct node *llHead;
```

So that the linked list head is intact.

Comment: We have to convert it-inplace

Answer (score 0):

The below algorithm is for the pre-order conversion. Similarly you can do the post-order.

```
 struct node
    {
        int data;
        struct node* left;
        struct node* right;
    };

    /Algorithm */
    struct node* bintree2listHelper(struct node *root)
    {
       if (root == NULL)
          return root;

       if (root->left != NULL)
       {
          struct node* left = bintree2listHelper(root->left);

          int flag =0;
     if(left->left == NULL)
    {
       left->left = left->right;
    }



          for(;left->left != NULL;)
          {
             struct node *temp = left;

             for (; temp->right!=NULL; )
             {
                flag = 1;
                temp=temp->right;
             }
             if(flag)
             {
                temp->left = root->right;
                left =left->left;
                break;
             }
             else
             {
                left =left->left;
             }

          }

          if(!flag)
             left->left = root->right;
       }

       if (root->right!=NULL)
       {
          struct node* right = bintree2listHelper(root->right);

          struct node *temp1= right;

          for (; right->left!=NULL; )
          {
             temp1 =right;
             right = right->left;
          }


          right->left = temp1->right;
       }
       return root;
    }

    struct node* bintreeTolist(struct node *root)
    {
        if (root == NULL)
            return root;

        root = bintree2listHelper(root);

        return (root);
    }

    struct node* newNode(int data)
    {
        struct node* new_node = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        new_node->data = data;
        new_node->left = new_node->right = NULL;
        return (new_node);
    }

    void printList(struct node *node)
    {
        while (node!=NULL)
        {
            printf("%d ", node->data);
            node = node->left;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
int main()
{
    typedef struct node node;
    node *root        = newNode(10);
    root->left        = newNode(12);
    root->right       = newNode(15);
    root->left->left  = newNode(25);
    root->left->right = newNode(30);
    root->right->left = newNode(36);
    root->left->right->left = newNode(78);
    root->left->right->right = newNode(77);
 node *head = bintreeTolist(root);

    // Print the converted list

   printList(head);
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pre-order Linked List

```
 public TreeNode flatten(TreeNode root) {
    if(root==null)
        return null;
    Stack<TreeNode> s=new Stack<TreeNode>();
    s.add(root);
    while(!s.isEmpty()){
        root=s.pop();
        if(root.right!=null)
            s.add(root.right);
        if(root.left!=null)
            s.add(root.left);
        if(!s.isEmpty())
            root.right=s.peek();
        else
            root.right=null;
        root.left=null;
    }
    return root;
 }
```

The above code gives the pre-order linked list with right pointer acting as the next pointer and the left pointer is ignored(i.e set to null). Its a slight modification of the iterative pre-order traversal code.
Idea is that once the processing of the current node is done, the top of the stack has the next node of the current node in the linked list.